# How to find duplicee

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that occasionally receives duplicate entries.

```
ID: Date:
  4    24
  4    24
  3    25
  3    25
  3    25
  5    10
```

I used the duplicated() function to return the rows that are duplicates.

```
ID: Date:
  4    24
  3    25
  3    25
```

This is great, but I would really like to get the row numbers of all the rows that are duplicates, like below.

```
ID: Date:
  4    24
  4    24
  3    25
  3    25
  3    25
```

Rows 1,2
Rows 3,4,5

Right now I called duplicated() with the fromLast variable activated, which works when there is only two duplications, but with 3 or more it seems to return the wrong value.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think it is a data.frame because it comes from the dbReadTable() function.

Comment: You should make it clear in the question that you are using `mysql`.  Tags are tiny to the eye. You should also include the code that got you to this point.  You'll get more help this way

Comment: I can include the code I used to get to this point, but I think it is pretty clear what I need and I don't think this code needs a specific example.

Comment: Do you mean to tag this "data.table" or "data.frame" perhaps? It could have an implication on the answers provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` twice, once each way. Like this:

```
> mydf[duplicated(mydf) | duplicated(mydf, fromLast=TRUE), ]
  ID. Date.
1   4    24
2   4    24
3   3    25
4   3    25
5   3    25
```

Comment: That was what I was doing before, and it seems to skip the top rows of anything that is replicated more than three times.

I get your table from above minus the
3  3  25
row

Comment: @user2712438, please post some sample data that demonstrates the problem you describe.

Comment: I am sorry. I was trying to post sample data but comments don't have the same format as questions and answers.

I was not capitalizing fromLast, which was causing the reverse to not happen, but I wasn't receieving any kind of error. It works great now, thanks for the help.